# Can I change my custom controller name in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, controller, url-routing

Hi I have a fully functioning Symfony2 application. Now as part of the SEO work I need to change the urls. I am able to change the last part of the url by changing in the routes file. But the string after domain name which is controller name, i can't change.

My current URL: http://example.com/logics/show

Updated URL should be http://example.com/logic/show

I have tried to rename the controller filename and class name. But its not worked. 
Please guide me how to change the controller name throughout the application or in URL ?

Comment: did you change the `routes` in your bundle's `routing.yml` ? also clear cache for production environment

Comment: Thanks Noman i have changed it in routing.yml file  prefix:   /logics to /logic

Comment: did it worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do a redirect is changing your routing.yml file.
For SEO reasons, you must redirect your old public URLs with a 301, if change is temporal you can do 302, Symfony allow do this easiest, like this example:

```
redirect_logic_show:
path: /logics/show
defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
    route: logic_show
    permanent: true
```

[For more info click here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_in_config.html#redirecting-using-a-route)